# Task.WaitAll method vs Parallel.Invoke method

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, task

I have sample code to compare processing time for Parallel approach and Task approach. The goal of this experiment is understanding of how do they work.

So my questions are:

1. Why Parallel worked faster then Task?
2. Do my results mean that I should use Parallel instead of Task?
3. Where should I use Task and where Parallel?
4. What benefits of using Task in comparison to Parallel?
5. Does Task is just a wrap for ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem method?

   ```
       public Task SomeLongOperation()
       {
           return Task.Delay(3000);
       }

       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
           Program p = new Program();
           List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

           tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => p.SomeLongOperation()));
           tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => p.SomeLongOperation()));

           var arr = tasks.ToArray();

           Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
           Task.WaitAll(arr);
           Console.WriteLine("Task wait all results: " + sw.Elapsed);
           sw.Stop();

           sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
           Parallel.Invoke(() => p.SomeLongOperation(), () => p.SomeLongOperation());
           Console.WriteLine("Parallel invoke results: " + sw.Elapsed);
           sw.Stop();

           Console.ReadKey();
       }
   ```

Here are my processing results: 
[image: results]

**EDIT:**

Changed code to look like this:

```
    Program p = new Program();
    Task[] tasks = new Task[2];

    Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    tasks[0] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => p.SomeLongOperation());
    tasks[1] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => p.SomeLongOperation());

    Task.WaitAll(tasks);
    Console.WriteLine("Task wait all results: " + sw.Elapsed);
    sw.Stop();

    sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    Parallel.Invoke(() => p.SomeLongOperation(), () => p.SomeLongOperation());
    Console.WriteLine("Parallel invoke results: " + sw.Elapsed);
    sw.Stop();
```

My new results:

[image: new results]

**EDIT 2:**
When I replaced code with Parallel.Invoke to be first and Task.WaitAll to be second the situation has been changed cardinally. Now Parallel is slower. It makes me think of incorrectness of my estimates. I changed code to look like this:

```
Program p = new Program();
Task[] tasks = new Task[2];

Stopwatch sw = null;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    Parallel.Invoke(() => p.SomeLongOperation(), () => p.SomeLongOperation());
    string res = sw.Elapsed.ToString();
    Console.WriteLine("Parallel invoke results: " + res);
    sw.Stop();
}

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    tasks[0] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => p.SomeLongOperation());
    tasks[1] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => p.SomeLongOperation());
    Task.WaitAll(tasks);
    string res2 = sw.Elapsed.ToString();
    Console.WriteLine("Task wait all results: " + res2);
    sw.Stop();
}
```

And here are my new results:

[image]

[image]

Now I can suggest that this experiment is much more clear. The results are almost the same. Sometimes Parallel and sometimes Task is faster. Now my questions are:

**1. Where should I use Task and where Parallel?**

**2. What benefits of using Task in comparison to Parallel?**

**3. Does Task is just a wrap for ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem method?**

Any helpful info that can clarify those questions are welcome.

Comment: tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => p.SomeLongOperation())); already started, but at that point your stopwatch has not started counting yet!

Comment: How should I change the code to make this experiment more clear?

Comment: Move it above the startnew()

Comment: BTW: you can call sw.Elapsed.Ticks or sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds, instead of 'sw.Elapsed',  the preceding 00:00... is not helpful.

Comment: I moved startnew method above tasks.Add(...). Now tasks much more slower then it was.

Comment: Perhaps there is an overhead due to ToArray method call?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

EDIT as of [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff963549.aspx) from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff963549.aspx):

Both Parallel and Task are wrappers for ThreadPool. Parallel invoke also awaits until all tasks are finished.

Related to your questions:

Using `Task`, `Parallel` or `ThreadPool` depends on the granularity of control you need to have on the execution of your parallel tasks. I'm personally got used to `Task.Factory.StartNew()`, but that's a personal opinion. The same relates to `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem()`

Additional Information: The first call to `Parallel.Invoke()` and `Task.Factory.StartNew()` might be slower due to internal initialization.

Comment: My results are always almost the same. Task.WaitAll is slower then Parallel.Invoke in any way. Perhaps I don't understand something or such comparison is incorrect. Any way I would like to get answers to my questions to clarify those approaches. I think answers to my questions will be useful for others too.

Comment: Just for information: How much time takes `SomeLongOperation()`?

Comment: looking at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff963549.aspx) MSDN article it says: "... Internally, Parallel.Invoke creates new tasks and waits for them. It uses methods of the Task class to do this. Here's an example. ..."

Comment: According to this article my test cases are the same. Thank you for your help. If you find all answers to my questions, please edit your answer so I can mark it as correct.

Comment: Please edit your answer => method StartNew instead of StartNow. Both Parallel and Task are wrappers for ThreadPool. Parallel invoke also awaits until all tasks will be finished.

Comment: No one should be using `Task.Factory.StartNew()` http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html

Answer (score 7):

If you start nongeneric Tasks(i.e. "void Tasks without a return value") and immediately `Wait` for them, use `Parallel.Invoke` instead. Your intent is immediately clear to the reader.

Use Tasks if:

- you do not Wait immediately
- you need return values
- you need to give parameters to the methods called
- you require `TaskCreationOptions` functionality
- you require `CancellationToken` or `TaskScheduler` functionality and don't want to use `ParallelOptions`
- basically, if you want more options or control

Yes, you can get around some of these, e.g. `Parallel.Invoke(() => p.OpWithToken(CancellationToken)` but that obfuscates your intent. `Parallel.Invoke` is for doing a bunch of work using as much CPU power as possible. It gets done, it doesn't deadlock, and you know this in advance.

---

Your testing is horrid though. The red flag would be that your long action is to wait 3000 milliseconds, yet your tests take less than a tenth of a millisecond.

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => p.SomeLongOperation());
```

StartNew takes an `Action`, and executes this in a new **main** `Task`. The action `() => SomeLongOperation()` creates a **subtask** `Task`. After this subtask is *created* (not completed), the call to `SomeLongOperation()` returns, and the **Action** is done. So the **main** `Task` is already completed after a tenth millisecond, while the two subtasks you have no reference to *are still running in the background.* The Parallel path also creates two subtasks, which it doesn't track at all, and returns.

The correct way would be `tasks[0] = p.SomeLongOperation();`, which assigns a running task to the array. Then `WaitAll` checks for the finishing of this task.