# Difference between Task.WaitAll and Parallel.Invoke?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, task, performance-testing, c#-5.0

I have come across two methods of invoking two methods in parallel way that are

```
Parallel.Invoke(new Action[]())
```

and

```
Task.WaitAll(new Task[]())
```

Can any body help to know what is the difference between them?

Comment: hi i think this has been covered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16101811/task-waitall-method-vs-parallel-invoke-method

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Task.Factory.StartNew vs. Parallel.Invoke](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14130929/task-factory-startnew-vs-parallel-invoke)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both the methods internally works on thread pool. There are different opinions which one to use amongst these two, I personally prefer Parallel.Invoke() for running actions parallel and wait for them after finishing.

Comment: I am not sure, if this is correct. Task.WaitAll only waits for the tasks. Lets say they are some asynchronous I/O tasks. In this case they can also run without a thread pool and Parallel.Invoke creates "normal" thread-pool-tasks and waits for them to be finished.

Comment: @SebastianStehle I agree with you! I was just trying to summarize things for most general cases. any ways thanks for taking that point out.